# Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle

Tags: java

```
Client: [Character: Demian[268482346] - Account: zayko - IP: 127.0.0.1] - Failed running: [C] 03 EnterWorld - L2J Server Version: ${l2j.revision} - DP Revision: ${l2jdp.revision} ; Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle
    at java.awt.Polygon.calculateBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Polygon.getBoundingBox(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Polygon.contains(Unknown Source)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.instancemanager.DimensionalRiftManager$DimensionalRiftRoom.checkIfInZone(DimensionalRiftManager.java:454)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.instancemanager.DimensionalRiftManager.checkIfInRiftZone(DimensionalRiftManager.java:255)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.network.clientpackets.EnterWorld.runImpl(EnterWorld.java:436)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.network.clientpackets.L2GameClientPacket.run(L2GameClientPacket.java:62)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.network.L2GameClient.run(L2GameClient.java:973)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a classpath problem. It would help to show both the code and the command line arguments to the JVM.